# How to use dispatch in order to push an array to reducer state?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux, react-redux

**My reducer with an array:**

```
const data = [
  [
    '23.9.2020',
    '11:20',
    'annual',
    'Some Data',
    'Some Data',
  ],
  [
    '11.6.2021',
    '13:45',
    'annual',
    'Some Data',
    'Some Data',
  ],
  ]

const dataPushReducer = (state = data, action) => {
  console.log(data)
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'Push':
      return {
        ...state,
        data: [state.data.concat(action.newItem)],
      }

    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

**The dispatch**

```
const newItem = ['SOME DATA', 'SOME DATA', 'SOME DATA', 'SOME DATA', 'ANOTHER DATA']
<button onClick={()=> dispatch(push(newItem)}
```

Dispatch not working - how to dispatch the action correctly so the new item is added and displayed in my other component as a new array (as shown in reducer)?

Comment: "Dispatch not working" please be more specific. Is there an error? Is something happening other than what you expect? What is `push`?

Comment: Case "push" should create copied data array and then add the new array into the copied array.

Comment: @radim1 Not the case, the function. You're calling `push(newItem)` what is push?

Comment: There's a lot of problems in your code, but to figure out the current one, you need to provide more details. 1) Your state is initialized to an array, but after your "Push" case it becomes an object. 2) The dispatch call is syntactically invalid, its missing a closing `)`. 3) You're referencing a `data` key in state that doesn't exist until its already been used (will never work).

Answer (score 1):

You have created your default state as an array, not an object.
So, you must return an array in your reducer.

Try this if you want to maintain your state as an array:

```
case 'Push':
  return [...state, action.newItem];
```

Or, if you turn your state into an object:

```
const INITIAL_STATE =  {
  data: [
    [
      '23.9.2020',
      '11:20',
      'annual',
      'Some Data',
      'Some Data',
    ],
    [
      '11.6.2021',
      '13:45',
      'annual',
      'Some Data',
      'Some Data',
    ],
  ]
}

const dataPushReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  console.log(data)
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'Push':
      return {
        ...state,
        data: [...state.data, action.newItem],
      }

    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

PS: If the `.concat()` function receives an array as parameter, it will extract the items of your array like this:

```
var array = [["john", 12], ["mary", 16]];
array.concat(["louis", 15]); 
// will results in [["john", 12], ["mary", 16], "louis", 15]
```

Comment: Thanks, the first solution works fine. I use the data as an array because I am using material UI table.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**
const newItem = ['SOME DATA', 'SOME DATA', 'SOME DATA', 'SOME DATA', 'ANOTHER DATA']
<button onClick={()=> dispatch({type:'Push',newItem})

Comment: Throws an error: cannot read property concat of undefined. Showing at the line:  ```data: [state.data.push(action.newItem)]```

Comment: **add this** case 'Push':
      return {
        ...state,
        data: state.data.concat(action.newItem),
      }

Comment: @radim.1 that's caused by your initialisation `state = data` should be `state = {data}`